# Vagrant's port forwarding not working

Tags: apache, http, centos, portforwarding, vagrant

I'm running into a small problem at the end of the [Getting Started guide for `vagrant`](http://vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/ports.html). I'm working on a CentOS basebox that has Apache2 running (provisioning via Puppet). I've set up port forwarding for web requests using the following line in `Vagrantfile`:

```
 config.vm.forward_port "web", 80, 4567
```

But when I make requests to that port, they fail. The error reported by Safari is 'Safari can’t open the page “http://localhost:4567/” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection.'

I did a `vagrant reload` and saw "[default] -- web: 80 => 4567 (adapter 1)" in the scroll, so where should I begin to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Comment: What does `curl -v 'http://localhost:4567/'` say?  Sometimes Safari is a bit too nice at hiding error messages.

Comment: Also, does `curl 'http://localhost:80'` from the VM itself work?  If not, the problem isn't the port forwarding.

Comment: @Steve Losh `curl` from within the VM is working. `curl` from the host gives me `(52) Empty reply from server`.

Comment: The vagrant reload help me on similar question...

Comment: For me the case was with symfony 3: - when run sudo php bin/console server:run which makes server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 then I cannot access from web browser, curl in virtual machine accessed. When ran sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 in web directory, I could access http://127.0.0.1:8082/app_dev.php . Do not understand why this happens, but works.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I'll make this an actual answer instead of just more comments.

First thing: try `curl 'http://localhost:80'` from within the VM.  If that doesn't work, then it's definitely not the port forwarding.

Next: try `curl -v 'http://localhost:4567/'` from your host machine.  Curl might give you a better error message than Safari.

I'd check that there are no firewalls set up restricting access to port 80.  The default Vagrant VM (Ubuntu) doesn't come with a firewall set up, but you said you're using something else, so it might be worth it to check.

If that's not it, try making something other than Apache listed on port 80.  Python ships with a simple HTTP server you can use -- go to the folder with `index.html` and run `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`, then try hitting that with curl from both boxes.  If that works, then it's probably an Apache configuration issue.  I don't have enough experience with Apache to help if that's the case (I use nginx).

Comment: Basically, I suck at RedHat and `iptables`. I checked to make sure the default policy was `ACCEPT` for incoming connections, but didn't pay attention to RedHat's custom rule chain, which has a catch-all `REJECT` rule as the last rule in the chain. tl;dr I had a firewall in the way and just didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks! That sneaky firewall rule is what caused my problems on RHEL 5.5.

Comment: I reprint Robert's comment below because it is such a trivial way to check: Run `service iptables stop` as root to quickly rule out a Guest firewall issue. Reenable it later if needed.

Comment: had same issue with a weird centos image; `iptables` was restricting almost everything. I followed this [iptable centos guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) (solution in [section 3 Writing a Simple Rule Set](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables#head-724ed81dbcd2b82b5fd3f648142796f3ce60c730)) and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: for me  curl was working inside so i enabled networking in `Vagrantfile` and ran command `vagrant reload`

Answer (score 275):

I wanted to add an additional note that often this is caused by the server within the VM because it binds to `127.0.0.1`, which is loopback. You'll want to make sure that the server is bound to `0.0.0.0` so that all interfaces can access it.

Some built-in app servers such as Django's development servers and some Ruby servers default to `127.0.0.1` by default so this is something to watch out for.

Other than that, what Steve said holds true: Make sure it works from within the VM and try some other simple servers to try and figure out if it is a configuration problem.

Comment: This was the fix needed for shotgun running webrick.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. To bind Torquebox to 0.0.0.0 run it with: torquebox run -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yep this was the problem. Need to bind to 0.0.0.0. I wonder if there's a way that Vagrant can automatically make this problem go away in the future?

Comment: same problem with sinatra and webrick: "set :bind, '0.0.0.0'" solved the issue

Comment: This fixed the problem for me with a nodejs server, binding to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This question helped me figure out how to perform this action with Rails - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668436/how-to-change-the-default-binding-ip-of-rails-4-2-development-server

Comment: I had the same issue with gatsbyjs, so I needed to run like `gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0`. Then `http://localhost:8000` works :)

Comment: Apologies for adding another useless comment.... BUT this worked for me too :D Thank you!!!

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem on CentOS 6.3 w/ NGINX and found the answer to be in the iptables on the vagrant box.

From bash on the vagrant box, follow these steps:

First list current iptable rules

```
iptables -L -v
```

Then flush current rules:

```
iptables -F
```

Allow SSH connections on tcp port 22

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Set default policies for INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT chains

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Set access for localhost

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Accept packets belonging to established and related connections

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Save settings

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

List modified rules

```
iptables -L -v
```

Curl localhost:[port#] or hit it in your browser from outside vagrant

More info on CentOS iptable configs found here:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up.  I had this same problem on Fedora 18, so it's not specific to CentOS.  I hope that helps someone else.  :)

Comment: This was me on CentOS. `service iptables stop`

Comment: `iptables -F` alone did it for me

Comment: I found a solid solution to this with some exec commands listed in this blog post to solve this same issue
http://techie-notebook.blogspot.com/2014/05/using-puppet-to-open-port-80-through.html
I had to replace my path with the ${os_path} sections as I didn't have that variable available.

Answer (score 27):

A better solution for me is disabling the firewall

```
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

Comment: +1 Worked for me. For using a local VirtualBox instance, I had no need for a firewall.

Comment: it's a good trick if you wanna a temporary fix

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another note like Mitchell as well. if my case I forward it to 6789 from 80

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:6789
```

And I got

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
```

Then, I used the IP address instead, it got the correct html message.