# Connection Reset when port forwarding with Vagrant

Tags: django, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant, portforwarding, connection-reset

I have Vagrant/VirtualBox running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS. I have configured Vagrant to forward the guest port 8000 to my host port 8888.

```
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 8000 => 8888 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
```

When the virtual machine starts up, I start a Django dev server on port 8000.

```
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Okay great, I can put it in the background and I can even `curl localhost:8000` and get some output from the server

```
<div id="explanation">
  <p>
    You're seeing this message because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in your
    Django settings file and you haven't configured any URLs. Get to work!
  </p>
</div>
```

But when I try to hit the server from my host machine with a Firefox/Chrome/Telnet I'm getting Connection Reset/Connection Lost/ERR_CONNECTION_RESET etc.

First I thought it may be some iptables thing, but it turns out Ubuntu has default allow everything. I also turned off the firewall on my host machine. How can I get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I had Django listening on 127.0.0.1:8000 (default)

As explained in Mitchell's answer here: [Vagrant's port forwarding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984217/vagrants-port-forwarding-not-working?rq=1) I should have been listening on 0.0.0.0. Here is a quote of his answer:

> I wanted to add an additional note that often this is caused by the
>   server within the VM because it binds to 127.0.0.1, which is loopback.
>   You'll want to make sure that the server is bound to 0.0.0.0 so that
>   all interfaces can access it.

If you're using Django, you want to start the dev server like this: `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: And if you're using Rails, and happened to get to this Django post, your corresponding `rails` options are `rails -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: You have just rocked my world buddy :)

Answer (score 4):

1). Project must be run as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.
if this is not fix your problem then

2). Open your Vagrantfile and add 
 
`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8001` this  after 

`# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080` line

This work in my case ;)

Note: This forward port info provided when run `vagrant up` 
`....`
`==> default: Forwarding ports...`

> `default: 8000 => 8001 (adapter 1)`
>       `default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [ssh tunneling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115906) with vagrant.
Open up a terminal and `cd` into the directory where your `Vagrantfile` is.
Assuming your vm is up and running (`vagrant up`) execute the following command.

```
# save vagrant ssh config to a file named `vagrant-ssh-config`
vagrant ssh-config > vagrant-ssh-config
```

Afterwards forward guest's port 8000 to host.

```
ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 -F vagrant-ssh-config default
```

Now just open your browser and check `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Note that the previous command will also open a shell on ssh server. If you want to open ssh tunnel without a shell on ssh server add `-N`

```
ssh -N -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 -F vagrant-ssh-config default
```

**Update: Oct 4 2019**

A simpler solution to forward port

```
vagrant ssh -- -N -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000
```

Tested on Vagrant 2.0.2, but may work for older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @GrvTyagi's answer.

I am using ubuntu : "hashicorp/bionic64"

My Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  #Ubuntu 18.04
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8080
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.gui = false
      vb.cpus = 2
      vb.memory = "4096"
    end
  
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  # your script to execute while provision the server goes here
  SHELL

end
```

For some reaseon default port (80) suggested by offical documentaion is not working. so below config will not work:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

TEst your port forwarding by running a simple server

```
python3 -m http.server 8081
```

You should able to connect with it from the host using the command

```
curl http://localhost:8080/ --trace-ascii dump.txt
```

Once successful,force run your application on host 0.0.0.0 and port 8081
running on localhost will not work.

```
yourappserver --bindhost 0.0.0.0 -bindport 8081
```

you should able to connect with it from the host by

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080
```