# Empty reply from server - can't connect to vagrant vm w/port forwarding

Tags: vagrant

I'm running werkzeug (as part of a Tilestache setup) inside a Vagrant VM, running ubuntu 'precise.'

In my Vagrantfile, I have:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

When I start the server in the VM, I see:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

If I `curl` that address from within the VM, I get the expected result. When I `curl` it from the host machine, I get:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

And Chrome says "No data received."

Troubleshooting info:

- The server responds to pings from the host machine
- a port sniffer verifies that the port is open
- running `netstat -ntlp | grep 8080` in the vm shows that the server is listening on 8080
- My local hostsfile doesn't have any weird conflicts
- I'm also forwarding 22 => 2222, and I can ssh in with no trouble
- I've disabled the firewall on the host, and i don't believe there's one on the guest (iptables and ufw are disabled, at least)
- I've set `auto_correct: true` in case there are conflicts (there aren't)

I know I could set up a private network, but I'd like to understand why this isn't working and how to troubleshoot it.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When running a server from within a VM, start the server on **0.0.0.0** instead of **127.0.0.1**.

127.0.0.1 is only accessible to the *local machine*, which for a VM means nothing outside of the VM can reach it! 0.0.0.0 is accessible from anywhere on the *local network*, which to a VM includes the host machine.

The answer came from here: [Connection Reset when port forwarding with Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157353/connection-reset-when-port-forwarding-with-vagrant)

(Which apparently got its answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999945/738675)

With help from: https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

#### Google-bait:

Here are the errors you might receive if this is the problem:

- Chrome: "No data received"
- Firefox: "The connection was reset - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."
- Safari: "Safari can’t open the page [URL] because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection"
- curl: "Empty reply from server"

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me (using the approach outlined by Truong Nguyen). Same error, "No data received", but using the forwarded port and localhost, i.e. 'localhost:8080' works fine.

Answer (score 23):

In the `/etc/hosts` inside the VM, change line

127.0.0.1 localhost -> 0.0.0.0 localhost
and then `restart server`

Comment: This works great.  Note that this setting is set on the vagrant guest, not on the host system.  Pretty obvious but less so when you come from a random google search for quick fix.

Comment: Ouch! Please do not do this. This is not the correct answer. Even if it's VM.

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: @JeffMcCune Do you care to elaborate?

Comment: it worked for me after doing `vagrant reload`..
thanx

Answer (score 2):

This can also be a problem with your firewall on the vagrant machine.  If you can curl the address while on the vagrant box, then check your firewalld settings or turn it off:

on CENTOS:

```
sudo service firewalld stop
```

Then you should update your firewalld settings and restart it ;)