# nvm ls-remote command results in "N/A"

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to install Node with nvm, but when I type any version it's not available. When I type `nvm ls-remote` I just just get "N/A".

I'm able to access the Internet, so I can't figure what could be going on.

Comment: Looks like maybe this issue got fixed? https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/554

Comment: This is most likely a problem with curl and not with nvm, please see my answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36300754/1439843) to fix curl.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**Update with comment from LJHarb, who maintains nvm.sh**

LJHarb suggests that a typical problem causing this is that "the SSL certificate authorities installed in your system have gone out of date". Checking this and trying to fix this would be a better first step.

In the case where you believe there *is* a problem on the nvm.sh side, LJHarb asks that users file a bug on [nvm.sh's issue tracker](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues).

Feel free to see the original text in the comments section.

Also, I'd like to point out that the below solutions are intended as workarounds only to be used temporarily if you're really in a bind. Permanently modifying the exported mirror or the nvm.sh script itself is not recommended.

**Edit**: Found easier fix

You can export the non https version of the mirror it uses to grab the stuff:

```sh
export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist
```

Then nvm works

**Pre edit**

Had the same problem just now.

Looks like by default it tries to use curl if it's available on your system.

I assume you're on linux also, so try running `curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` and see if you get the same error I did:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

Maybe some cert is expired or otherwise misconfigured (or someone's doing something nasty), until it's fixed, if you don't mind going around the security issue, you can find the nvm.sh file (should be at `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` if you followed the install info), and you can add a `-k` on line 17 after the curl, so it looks like this:

```
-- nvm.sh --
nvm_download() {
16  if nvm_has "curl"; then
17    curl -k $*
18  elif nvm_has "wget"; then
19    # Emulate curl with wget
...
}
```

Don't forget to restart your shell, then try `nvm ls-remote`. Assuming the fix worked, you should be able to use nvm now.

Comment: Right now I am on a vagrant box (laravel/homestead) on Mac OS 10.9. The box it fresh, so there shouldn't be anything nasty. Funny thing is, this is the same edition of the box I have on Windows PC and it works just fine.

Comment: It wouldn't be your box, it's on the mirror's end, I don't think there's much we can do to fix the root of the issue on our end. See my easier suggestion in the edit. Good luck!

Comment: I get no curl error. Instead I get an HTML error doc for `301 moved permanently`. When I echo that string, I get `https://nodejs.org/dist` which is absolutely correct from what I can tell.

Comment: BTW, you original solution to add `-k` after `curl` solved the problem. The `export` solution did not work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have `curl -q` and replace witth `-k` solution worked! The export didnt work also. Thanks!

Comment: I met the same symptom on Kubuntu 16.04. The problem was that curl expected `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, while in 16.04 it is in different place and is called differently: `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. Linking file to the position where curl expects it solved the issue: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs/ && sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`.

Comment: I'm the http://nvm.sh maintainer. Please DO NOT edit nvm.sh directly. If you have SSL issues, *fix your SSL issues*.

Comment: @LJHarb any ideas on what ssl issues users might be running into they can fix? As I recall (though this a while ago for me) I didn't change anything when I had this issue. `nvm ls-remote` just stopped working for a few hours, then went back to normal. Happy to update the answer with your input.

Comment: Typically it's that the SSL certificate authorities installed in your system have gone out of date. In this specific case, the SSL certificate configurations on nodejs.org and iojs.org  were temporarily altered - ie, it was out of user control, and was fixed without user intervention.

In general in these situations, please file issues on http://nvm.sh rather than posting a random Stack Overflow question, and you'll get a fast response with far more context than you can get here.

Comment: @LJHarb Added your input to the answer. Hopefully that captures what you're saying. If not, feel free to edit and add as well :)

Comment: Thanks, much obliged :-) I want to fix bugs for everyone, and make sure future nvm upgrades are seamless

Comment: In my case I am getting below response for 
`curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR`

`curl (7) Failed to connect to nodejs.org port 80: Network is unreachable`

though I am able to `curl google.com` and able to open `http://nodejs.org/dist/` from browser

Comment: The golden command line was for me `export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist`

Comment: ```export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist/``` worked for me the / was needed as the original link now redirects to the / one

Comment: Over a year I've had this problem... Thank you sir.

PS> Didn't work for me until I put the -k command into nvm.sh

Comment: Doing this in Windows bash, and adding the `-k` flag to curl command in `nvm.sh` fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: pre-edit solution worked!

Answer (score 54):

Create a file called

`~/.curlrc`

In it insert one line

```
-k
```

Then try again.

(Warning: This answer *disables curl's CA verification*.  "-k" is shorthand for "--insecure".  Don't copy it blindly.  -edit)

Comment: Works like a magic!

Comment: you should add the meaning this option

Comment: From `man curl`: -k, --insecure
              (TLS)  By  default,  every  SSL connection curl makes is verified to be secure. This option allows curl to
              proceed and operate even for server connections otherwise considered insecure.

              The server connection is verified by making sure the server's certificate contains the right name and ver‐
              ifies successfully using the cert store.

              See this online resource for further details:
               https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: `echo "-k" > ~/.curlrc`

Comment: This makes your curl less secure, BE CAREFUL! (fixing it is easy, just look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36300754/1439843)

Answer (score 39):

Most likely this is caused by curl not being able to use certificates for https urls (verify with `curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR`). **Instead of using the http url as workaround, it is better to fix curl by pointing it to the appropriate CA bundle ([source1](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160909))**. Add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

- **Ubuntu** (assuming you have the `ca-certificates` package installed)

  ```
  export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  ```
- **RHEL 7**

  ```
  export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  ```

Comment: This is the right answer. I did the first one initially and the problem returned.

Comment: May also depend on your flavor of Linux, on my RHEL7 I had to instead use "export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

Comment: @EricSoyke thanks, updated the answer with RHEL bundle location

Answer (score 15):

Changing from

`export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist/`

To

`export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist/`

Worked for me :)

Comment: This fixed it for me

Answer (score 11):

For others like me who land here after a search:

I had the same issue today on Ubuntu, but the cause turned out to be that the `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file was completely empty.

The solution was to run:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html

Comment: This didn't do anything for me (didn't work), but seems to point the right direction of the issue (Expired certificates), so give it a try

Comment: That fixed all for me.

Comment: I added the `--fresh` option (as recommended via another site). Then `nvm ls-remote` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

It seems the '/' is missing from the end of the url, that is why the 301 permanently moved message. 
So changing the link in nvm.sh from

http://nodejs.org/dist

to

http://nodejs.org/dist/

makes it work.

Comment: to check this quickly `cat nvm.sh | grep "curl.*nodejs.org/dist"` , and check the results

Answer (score 9):

If you are using nvm behide a proxy you need set proxy config to curl

edit or create the file **~/.curlrc** and add this line with your proxy

```
echo 'proxy=http://<proxy-user>:<proxy-pass>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>' >> ~/.curlrc
```

if your proxy does not need a user and password, you can use it:

```
echo 'proxy=http:<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>' >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: I am using a ubuntu docker image and only this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, but none of the other solutions helped. `curl -v $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR/` showed TLS 1.2 and no problem with certs. When I tried `which curl`, it turns out that I had an anaconda3/bin directory in my PATH, which has it's own version of curl (not sure why they need that). Once I fixed my path, `nvm ls-remote` worked just fine. Hope this helps save someone else some frustration.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by manually upgrading `nvm` to the latest version

```
(
  cd "$NVM_DIR"
  git fetch --tags origin
  git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags --match "v[0-9]*" $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)`
) && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue lately. Changing to `http://nodejs.org/dist/` did not work for me because it redirecrs to https and that results in NA from `nvm ls-remote`. So what I've done was:

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

Then I edited `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` and changed

`http://nodejs.org/dist` to `https://nodejs.org/dist/` (added https and "/" to avoid redirects) and it worked

Comment: The end `/` after `dist` did the trick. Thanks.

Just for additional info, rather than editing the `nvm.sh`, you can just add `export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=https://nodejs.org/dist/` to one of the following files  `~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on WSL2. I also have an https_proxy environment variable set to my company's https_proxy server.

When working inside the company VPN, this did not work since (I believe) WSL2 have a problem using the proxy settings correctly.

Outside the company VPN, un-setting this environment variable, fixed the problem.

so (outside the VPN):

```
unset https_proxy
```

and then

```
nvm ls-remote --lts
```

worked.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario could be rare, but just want to add another data point to this thread:

Because of my local setup issue, I don't want to install `curl`, and I explicitly set an alias for `curl` to warn myself from installing it in the future, which results in the `nvm` believing I have curl available and use `curl`to download. It worked after I removed my alias.

**Solution**

check explicitly if your `curl` or `wget` is usable.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that allowed me to do what I wanted even though `nvm list available` still isn't working after trying everything on this list.

It might be an old version of curl but working on a server shared with others and not allowed to update that until I wait a few days for approval.

Ultimately I went to: https://nodejs.org/download/release/ I found the newest version of node I was looking to install, which was 16, located here: https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v16.x/

Then simply ran:

> nvm install v16.16.0

And the install worked fine even if I couldn't pull available versions via nvm!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with dns; for where I work dns is set automatically and when I ran `curl -v $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR/` it lead to `Could not resolve host: nodejs.org` and `ping nodejs.org` ran to `Temporary failure in name resolution`. So I changed `/etc/resolv.conf` and added

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then `nvm install --lts` started working.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem when using Vagrant 1.7.1 running a Ubuntu 14.04 box under Virtual Box 4.3.30 on Windows 7. I tried suggestions above and nothing worked for me. I found this post over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840098/empty-reply-from-server-cant-connect-to-vagrant-vm-w-port-forwarding) that was related to the Curl error I was getting when trying to run: `curl $NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR`
 The error was: `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`
 I was able to follow a suggestion on that post and then once I restarted my Vagrant box with a `vagrant reload` I was able to run `nvm ls-remote` and see a list of versions of node and install. Here is what I did on the vagrant box: `cd /etc/`

```
sudo nano hosts
```

changed 127.0.0.1 localhost

to:

0.0.0.0 localhost

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue. Thanks@ [Truong Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2663633/truong-nguyen)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this will work

`nvm alias default node` points "default" at the latest installed Node version (8.11.1).

Comment: wait ... do I need node before I can install nvm ?

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me in my linux:

export NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=http://nodejs.org/dist

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu server, the interfaces aren't setup with DHCP by default. I forgot about this and after I installed nvm, I rebooted which lost network connectivity and didn't realize it. I know that you had network connectivity, but I am posting this as something for posterity to check. Stupid simple thing that can be easily forgotten/missed.

Answer (score 0):

For `nvm-windows` use `nvm list available`

Comment: this also return `N/A` for me. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in ubuntu and I found that the issue is not related NVM but it's not able to reach to node repository due to Proxy setting so I did the below steps and then it worked as expected

- open  /etc/apt/apt.conf

  nano  /etc/apt/apt.conf
- Add the following to the above opened file

`Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy-user>:<proxy-pass>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>"`
`Acquire::https::proxy "http://<proxy-user>:<proxy-pass>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>"`

- run below command

  `export http_proxy='http://<proxy-user>:<proxy-pass>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>'`

  `export https_proxy='http://<proxy-user>:<proxy-pass>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>'`

then your proxy issue will resolve and gives list of node version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any `proxy/VPN`, **disable** it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, introduce my device and environment: macOS and shadowsocks proxy.

I take steps to fix it. `nvm ls-remote command results in "N/A"`

I try every method on the internet and i find one method is in effect for me.

`vim ~/.curlrc` and then add some sentences like:

```
proxy="http:<proxy-password>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>"
proxy="socks5:<proxy-password>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>"
// if you have username, you can do this
proxy="http:<proxy-username>:<proxy-password>@<proxy-url>:<proxy-port>"
// it's my example, you need find your url and port, here password is faked.
proxy="socks5://6Bn23U5ceOMS4g@127.0.0.1:1080"
proxy="http://6Bn23U5ceOMS4g@127.0.0.1:1081"
```

finally, `source ~/.curlrc`

congrats~

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while using the WSL, then I was able fix it after upgrading from WSL1 to WSL2. I hope that helps.