# App Engine Go SDK web server running in Vagrant guest (with port forwarding) not reachable from host

Tags: google-app-engine, go, vagrant

I'm running GAE dev server within a Vagrant guest precise64 box with the following network setup (in my Vagrantfile):

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9090
end
```

Which does its thing:

```
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 8080 => 9090 (adapter 1)
```

I start my App Engine server with:

```
goapp serve
```

or

```
dev_appserver.py myappfolder
```

This starts app engine dev server as expected:

```
INFO 2013-11-22 dispatcher.py] Starting module running at: http://localhost:8080
```

In all cases, **I'm able to ssh in to the Vagrant guest and curl localhost:8080 successfully**.

Unfortunately, from the *host* I'm unable to get a response from localhost:9090 when running GAE dev web server.  Additionally, I've made sure that I don't have anything interfering with the port 9090 on the host machine. *Also, I'm almost positive this isn't related to Vagrant as I spun up a quick node.js web server on 8080 and was able to reach it from the host.  What am I missing?!!!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must run the [Google App Engine Go dev web server](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver) on 0.0.0.0 when leveraging Vagrant port forwarding.  Like so:

```
goapp serve -host=0.0.0.0
```

See [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984217/vagrants-port-forwarding-not-working) for more info on ensuring the guest web server is **not bound to 127.0.0.1** which is loopback.  Web servers that bind to 127.0.0.1 (like App Engine Go dev web server does) by default should be overridden to use 0.0.0.0.

Comment: `goapp serve -host ::` is equivalent, and just a little less typing

Comment: I did not know that. So, that is the IPv6 "unspecified" address. Cool. Less typing is always appreciated. Thanks @Dave

Comment: the `--host=` argument is also relevant for the other language SDKs when running in vagrant.