# unable to connect to localhost:8080 with Vagrant and Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant

I tried to install Vagrant and Ubuntu on mac os 10.9.4 to make a local development server following this great instructions by @fideloper: [Vagrant and Apache](http://serversforhackers.com/editions/2014/02/25/vagrant-apache/).

the Vagrantfile contains:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html"
```

evreything worked fine during the process: Vagrant and virtualbox are installed, Apache is installed on the guest.

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984217/vagrants-port-forwarding-not-working/5992293#5992293), i tried:

- on the guest, `curl 'http://localhost:80'` returns an html with a file listing
- on the host, `curl -v 'http://localhost:8080'` returns the
  same page.

but the browser says `this webpage is not available` at localhost:8080.

why the browser is not displaying localhost:8080?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html"
```

will overwrite whatever's in the server's `/var/www/html` directory with whatever is in your host machine's `"."` directory (the shared directory).

There's no longer Apache's default `index.html` file at `/var/www/html/index.html` because you mounted your shared directory at that location in the Vagrant synced_folder settings.

From what you're saying, it's working totally normally and you can just start adding your own .html files into your shared folder and go! You just don't have a .html file in your shared directory to serve, so Apache's falling back to showing the index of the files there.

Comment: Everything works normally except the browser says `this webpage is not available` and doesn't show anything, even if there are some html files inside the folder…

Comment: And suddenly it's working !!! I just vagrant reloaded many times since yesterday… and for no apparent reason it suddenly started to work. thank you so much.