# PHP Built in Server Not Working with Vagrant in Host Machine

Tags: php, vagrant, php-builtin-server

I'm using vagrant box hashicorp/precise64, Ubuntu 14.04, and PHP 5.6.

My Vagrantfile has `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080`

I'm trying to test with the built in PHP server using: `php -S localhost:80`

The server is up in the virtual machine. I confirmed this with `wget`. However, I cannot access it from my host machine. My browser can't reach `localhost`.

Note: Apache and NodeJS servers both work, but not the built in PHP server.

Comment: @PedroLobito - Uh, why exactly?

Comment: Did you try using an alternative port  ?

Comment: It takes ages to setup and most of the time it doesn't work properly. It's 2016, but vagrant still in 95.

Comment: @PedroLobito do you have any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: @GayanL yes, 8080, 8000

Comment: @Linny To develop with laravel you don't need vagrant, just install gulp, node, etc.., it takes 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999945/4736111

I had to use 0.0.0.0 for the address of the php server.
Should have been `php -S 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: hey, what ? i'm using win8 and if i get into my vm php is working. The problem is if i try from my host wich is in windows. I go to whatever.dev and it shows all php tags! what are you suggesting to do with that 0.0.0.0 ? can you please explain me ?